# vim auto indent suddenly stopped working

Tags: neovim, indentation

Recently, neovim auto indent was working fine, but suddenly it stopped working.

here is my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`:-

```
call plug#begin('~/.local/share/nvim/plugged')

Plug 'townk/vim-autoclose'

Plug 'wesq3/vim-windowswap'

Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'

Plug 'vim-scripts/c.vim'

Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'

Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

Plug 'arcticicestudio/nord-vim'

set number

call plug#end()


colorscheme nord
```

This is the same file as it was when neovim indentation was working correctly.
I just found out that indentation is also not working in vim.

Comment: Have any of the plugins changed?