# vim suddenly stops indenting and uses tabs instead of spaces

Tags: neovim, indentation

every now and then my neovim just stops the correct indenting and i have to restart the session.
Besides the indenting, some plugins seem to stop working as well as some built in function like the <kbd>o</kbd> key. It then places the cursor to the very beginning of the next line. Very annoying.

I've already tried to remove all the plugins and install only the basic and necessary ones, and it seemed to work. Than I've added one after one to narrow this issue. After I thought I've found the bad plugin I removed it but some days later the issue showed up again.

Is there a better way to get the reason for this kind of issue?

You can find [my dotfiles at my github account](https://github.com/Artem-Schander/dotfiles)

And I know, there is a [similar issue](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15152/vim-auto-indent-suddenly-stopped-working) at this Q&A. But I don't think it's the same. And besides that, it has no answer.

Comment: Based on the answer below, could you determine if `paste` is set the next time this happens?

Comment: Yep, sure. I'll do so. But it could take a while. It doesn't happen that regularly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also get this from time to time when I paste into vim. I usually do `:set nopaste` and reindent (with `gg=G`).

Comment: For the time being, thanks for the answer. As soon as I get that issue again, I'll upvote and accept, if it solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks again :) i'm curious what causes this setting to get chaged. BTW you could use `:%retab` instead of `gg=G` which not always does a decent job.